# Adding a single element onto a list until a certain point

Tags: list, recursion, racket

I want to make a function that given a list and a natural number, adds zeros onto the list so the length of the list equals the natural number. What is an efficient way of doing this so instead of making every element zero, it does what it's supposed to do

```
(define (zero-list loz alon)
  (cond
    [(empty? loz) empty]
    [(= (-(length loz) 1) alon) (cons 0 loz)]
    [else (cons 0 (zero-list (rest loz)))]))
```

Example: 
`(zero-list (list 1 2 3) 5)) -> (list 0 0)` so (length (list 1 2 3)) + (length (list 0 0)) = 5

Answer (score 1):

Use [`make-list`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._make-list%29%29) to generate a list that has the appropriate number of 0s (i.e. difference between the number and the length of the input list):

```
(define (zero-list l n) 
  (make-list (- n (length l)) 0))

(zero-list (list 1 2 3) 5) ; -> (list 0 0)
```